# Add hyper link to a excel spread sheet in a VBA email

Tags: excel, vba, email, hyperlink

Im looking to add a link to the spread sheet that sends a email, so for example under the info in the email there is a blue link that will open the spreadsheet.

The spreadsheet will be accessible by the recipient through their computer.

Any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: Is the email being created through a macro? If so some code may help. Why not just attach the file?

Answer (score 0):

You say "the spread sheet that sends an email", so I assume there's a macro that gets executed in said file. You can get and use the path as follows:

```
Dim pathToFile As String       
pathToFile = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
```